# Write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named invoice_balance

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Write a script that creates and calls a stored procedure named invoice_balance. This stored procedure should use two variables to store (1) the count of all of the invoices in the Invoices table that have a balance due and (2) the sum of the balances due for all of those invoices. If that total balance due is greater than or equal to $30,000, the stored procedure should display a result set that displays the values of both variables. Otherwise, the procedure should display a result set that displays a message like this: Total balance due is less than $30,000.

```
SELECT sum(dueBalance) FROM invoice

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;                ;//drop if already test name procedure avilable

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test()

BEGIN

DECLARE countInvoice int;                                   //declaring two variable countInvoice and sumdueBalance ​

DECLARE sumdueBalance decimal(10,8);

   SELECT count(*) into countInvoice  //put total count in countInvoice

   FROM invoice;

   SELECT sum(dueBalance) into sumdueBalance   //put sum in sumdueBalance

   FROM invoice;

   if countprod>=30000 then   

   select countInvoice , sumdueBalance as col1;    //col1 is name for new column

   else

   select 'Total balance due is less than $30,000.';

   end if;

END //

DELIMITER ;

call test()
```

I wrote this script but it is giving me an error 1064.
SCHEMA GIVEN
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JAeBc2h_5-z7La6nizFgIRDL1pjKDDz2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: and how can we help you?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test' at line 3

Comment: Sorry,sir, but MySQL and SQL Server are different RDBMSes. Would you be so kind to clarify which one you use

Comment: I am using My SQL.

Comment: This Code is still giving me errors i don't know i have done wrong. This should give me something like this.Total balance due is less than $30,000

Answer (score 0):

as i remember there is sql syntax error in your script and this part the select into is not how it suppose to be in mysql.

SELECT count(*) into countInvoice can be rewrite in mysql:

```
insert into countInvoice
select count(*) from invoice;
```